# display record with specific date in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to select record with certain date and id. My datetime format in database is 2018-02-23 08:38:45. I've try this in my model but it always return the records with specific id only. My date format in `$tgl` is 23-01-2018 so I change the format using `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tgl) );`

```
public function spesific_odontogram($id_pasien, $date){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM odontogram WHERE DATE('inserted_at') = $date AND id_pasien=$id_pasien";
    $record = $this->db->query($query);
    if ($record->row_array()>0) {
        return $record->result_array();
    }
    return false;
    //return $record;
}
```

Here's my controller

```
public function spesific_odontogram(){
    $id_pasien=$_POST['id_pasien'];
    $tgl=$_POST['tgl'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tgl) );
    $data['record']=$this->m_pasien->spesific_odontogram($id_pasien, $date);
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
          echo json_encode($data);
          exit;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hey there!  When you say "I've try this in my model but it always return the records with specific id only" isn't that because you are passing a specific id here `id_pasien=$id_pasien`?? Unrelated: instead of `$record->row_array()>0` you should do `$record->num_rows() > 0`

Comment: What spacing are you referring to?

Comment: @Alex nope, I just try it

Comment: Again what did you try? I didn't make any recommendations here. Just an unrelated thing that won't effect the outcome whatsoever but is generally preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Date variable like '$date' instead of $date. Also make sure date format are same

```
public function spesific_odontogram($id_pasien, $date){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM odontogram WHERE inserted_at = '$date' AND id_pasien=$id_pasien");

if ($query->row_array()>0) {
    return $query->result_array();
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query on your model :

```
public function spesific_odontogram($id_pasien, $date){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM odontogram WHERE inserted_at >= $date AND inserted_at < $date + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND id_pasien=$id_pasien";
    $record = $this->db->query($query);
    if ($record->row_array()>0) {
        return $record->result_array();
    }
    return false;
    //return $record;
}
```

It basically check for only matches date record without calculate `DATE()` value of every row

Comment: it think the problem is in the format in date. In my database the datetime format is different with the $date in the model. I've try it but it returns false.

Comment: well you are missing the H:i:s in the one from the model, and you can't get it to convert right because you don't have all the info in the first place so it will always evaluate to false unless you just match the date without the H:i:s which requires you to convert the mysql date to `Y-m-d` on-the-fly for comparison

Comment: @Alex I change the $date in controller to $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($tgl) ); , and chage my todel query to $query = "SELECT * FROM odontogram WHERE inserted_at($date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND id_pasien=$id_pasien";   but it get error

Comment: I said it wouldn't work ("you can't get it to convert right because you don't have all the info") because "$tgl is 23-01-2018" it doesn't have the H:i:s information to begin with... even if you convert you end up with a H:i:s of `2018-01-23 00:00:00`, you see? either you get a $tgl with all the info or you understand that the date in the *database* will have to be converted to a format like `2018-01-23` without H:i:s ... but thats only if you don't care about the *specific* timestamp and just want to match the *day*

Comment: @Nadia have you used `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tgl) );` on your controller?

Comment: @HastaDhana finally I did it by change the timestamp format to date in my database

Comment: @Nadia actually you dont have to change from timestamp to date format since the query above will select record matching between `23-01-2018 00:00:00` and `24-01-2018 00:00:00`